# what do I call the trailing value after last slash in a url and how to get it in php

Tags: php, apache, url

I'm new to PHP and web, and I was wondering, in some URLs what do we call the last string value after the last slash. for example **"abc123"** in this url

**URL 1**

```
 http://www.example.com/folder1/abc123
```

---

I know about the URL `parameters` that is exist after a `?` question mark and how to get it inside my PHP scripts, like

**URL 2**

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/phpscript1.php?name=mike&age=24
```

when the browser requests this resource from the web server, the web server (Apache for example) are going to invoke the php module which will try to parse **`phpscript1.php`** giving him the data he needs to work. in this example I can see the `name` and `age` parameters inside my phpscript1.php file like this

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$age= $_GET['age'];
```

---

**Q1**- In URL1 what do I call **"abc123"** ? parameters ?

**Q2** In URL1 how the web server is going to deal with this request? will it try to find a resource that is called `"/folder1/abc123"` and just send it blindly to the browser ? for example if I have a file on the server that has the name `"abc123"` inside the folder `"/folder1/"`, is it going to be sent to the browser ?

**Q3** in URL1 how do I get the value **"abc123"** inside my PHP scripts? or even which is more important, **which PHP script are going to be invoked** by the PHP module to handle this request?

Comment: Those are not parameters or such thing. The request simply names a `path` that is requested. How that is interpreted is up to _you_. Typically a php application relies on "rewriting" of incoming requests. _How_ that rewriting is implemented depends, as already said, on _you_.

Comment: @arkascha I'm sorry what do you mean by "rewriting of incoming requests" ?

Comment: A simple google search for "rewrite request" would have answered that...

Comment: @arkascha I wasn't know that it is a famous "term" that a search for it would give me information. I thought It is a part from your comment that only you know what does it mean, but thanks. now I know there is a known thing in web called "rewrite request" and I'm already in this moment reading every thing about it. thanks

Comment: Sorry if I sounded arrogant. My bad. Rewriting is a basic thing when it comes to web page design and operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1- In URL1 what do I call "abc123" ? parameters ?

This is simply part of the path.

> Q2 In URL1 how the web server is going to deal with this request? will
>   it try to find a resource that is called "/folder1/abc123" and just
>   send it blindly to the browser ? for example if I have a file on the
>   server that has the name "abc123" inside the folder "/folder1/", is it
>   going to be sent to the browser ?

It depends on how your server is configured. Apache will look for the default document, which is defined in the httpd.conf file. It will likely look first for a file called index.html or index.php, but you can set it to look for other things, too. It will likely assume that the part after the last / is the filename, unless it's a folder name.

> Q3 in URL1 how do I get the value "abc123" inside my PHP scripts? or
>   even which is more important, which PHP script are going to be invoked
>   by the PHP module to handle this request?

You should look up the $_SERVER superglobal. It will likely have what you're looking for:

http://php.net/reserved.variables.server

Answer (score 1):

**Q1)** Default that URL is pointing at the folder `/folder1` and a file without extension `abc123`.

If you have [Mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled, you can change the url structure via [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) so that `GET` parameters are shown like that. See this post [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained#20563773)

**Q2)** Default it will try to open that file, abc123, if it does not exist - it will must likely return 404 error.

**Q3)** I think this is answered in Q1 and Q2.

Comment: thanks. for Q2 does it mean that in web applications that apply these URLS like `user/65421` , `user/13456` , `user/9852` they have a file called `65421` and a file called `13456` and `9852` inside the user folder ?

Comment: @user56489870 No, they have created a .htaccess rule that takes user=65421 and translates it to user/65421.  Check my reference in the post or this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049 or simply google "htaccess pretty urls" :)

Comment: thank you very much that is exactly what I needed to know. I guess you mean translate `user/65421` to `user=65421` not the other way, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, Is this what arkascha did mean by saying "rewriting incoming requests" in his comment ?

Comment: @user56489870 Yea - basically your code will work and look the same way as when GET parameters are user=65421, but the web-server will also understand user/65421 if you define it like that in .htaccess.

Yes that is what he ment - some frameworks does it differently, using routing classes. Wordpress uses the .htaccess method with mod_rewrite to rewrite the requests.

Comment: So yes if you define that rule in .htaccess it will rewrite user/65421 to user=65421 so your script understands it correct.

Comment: thaaaank you very much, now I got the picture very well, I hope I can give you 50000 helpful vote ups, thank you so much for your time

Comment: Haha no problem mate :)